# How long does it take for oil to coalesce in water?

Tags: surface-tension, diffusion, brownian-motion, bubbles

I was studying the process of coalescence in emulsions. We considered $N$ bubbles of liquid 1 floating in liquid 2. The result we derived, is that if there are some dissipative forces (diffusion) the most stable configuration is for the $N$ bubbles to coalesce/fusion and become 1 bubble (to reduce surface tension).

So I tried to make the experiment at home to see how long would it take. I emulsified oil in water. After one day, it has not changed much.

I tried to estimate the time it would take using Stokes-Einstein equation:
\begin{equation}
D=\frac{k_{\rm B}T}{6\pi \eta r}
\end{equation}
where $\eta$ is the viscosity of (olive) oil (?) and $r$ the radius of the bubbles (about 1 mm).

And then using the result of Brownian motion for 2D:
$$\overline{x^2}=4Dt$$
I replaced $\overline{x^2}$ by the surface of my container, about $R=$ 4 cm of radius so $\overline{x^2}=\pi R^2$. Mixing both equations, I can derive the time it takes (for room temperature). But I get an enormous duration of $10^5$ years.

Is this the true value or I am doing something wrong?

Update: Day five, the smallest bubbles ($r<1$ mm) are gone but still $N>100$.

Update2: Day six. No coalescence. I stopped the experiment.

Update3: Obvious problem of leaving the experiment for so long is that the water starts to evaporate.

Maybe the $10^5$ years was the right answer?

Comment: are you sure you want to use the Stokes-Einstein equation, since it is specifically for low Reynold's number?

Comment: A few points : 1. olive oil is not pure, so don't expect to see a real phase separation. 2. In your calculation, you should replace $x$ not by $R$, but by the average distance $d$ between the bubbles. 3. Gravity plays also a role since oil is less dense. Personnally, I would rather write $t=(R\rho v /gv\Delta \rho)^{1/2}$ that womes out from $ma=F$ with $v$ the volume of the small bubbles and $\rho$ their density, and $\Delta\rho$ the difference of density with water.

Comment: If you make the oil droplets too small, they will not coalesce.  Example: milk is not actually white.  It is composed of extremely small and clear droplets ("casein micelles") uniformly dispersed through water, that will not coalesce no matter how long you wait.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk#Physical_and_chemical_properties